# Source of variance in execution time?

Tags: c++

I would like to inquire about the source of execution time variance observed when profiling certain mathematical operations. I am observing a few distinct differences and I was hoping someone could shed a little light on the matter:

**Observation 1**: when profiling a mathematical operation, different execution times are observed. As an example of what I mean, if the following code were compiled and the resulting code was executed 10 separate times, I would observe ten different execution times. (furthermore, as expected, the execution time would depend on whether method 1 or method 2 were used).

```
int main()
{
    unsigned x { 0xFFFFFFFF };
    unsigned y; 
    int MAX_LOOP { 1000 };
    boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOP; i++ )
    {
        y = x >> 31;   // Method 1
    //  y = x/2^31;    // Method 2 (note: this expression is expanded in the actual code)
    }
    boost::posix_time::ptime stop = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration = start - stop;

    // output to std::cout not shown...
}
```

Method 1 yields execution times averaging [mean +/- std. dev.] 575us +/- 50us (!!), whereas method 2 yields execution times averaging 12.9us +/-1.6us.

Method 2 does not concern me so much, but method 1 seems to have rather high variance. In fact, the range of times observed with method 1 was 190 us! This range of execution times is somewhat startling to me. My question is, should I be startled by this range of execution times? Is there a good explanation for this variance?

**Observation 2**: The execution time does not scale with the number of loops performed within the code. The above statistics were based on a MAX_LOOP value of 1e3. If I increase MAX_LOOP to 1e8, then I observed method 1 to require 180.487ms +/- 3.139ms, whereas method 2 required 1021.825ms +/- 16.597ms. The increase in execution time does not scale with the increase in the number of absolute executions required. That is:

- Ratio of Loop Counts: 1e8/1e3 = 1e5
- Ratio of bit-shift division profile time: 180487/575 = 313
- Ratio of regular integer division profile time: 1021825/12.9 = 79211

Using method 1 (bit shift division), the performance gain goes from essentially 575ns/division to 1.805ns/division. Conversely, the regular integer division goes from 13ns/division" to 10.22ns/"division. Regular division appears to scale linearly with the number of loop iterations performed, but the bit-shifting method seemed to exhibit greatly-improved performance when the number of loop iterations was great.

Have I made an error somewhere that is not obvious to me? If not, can anyone explain why the performance gain for the bit-shifting division changes so much under these circumstances? Is it possible that the compiler is using default optimizations? (and if so, (a) can optimizations really be *that* good?, and (b) how would I find out what optimizations the compiler is using by default?)

Other things that might be important:

- Apple LLVM ver 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
- Boost 1.65.1 (used strictly for timing)
- Execution taking place on one core of my laptop's i7
- compiled without optimizations using: clang++ -std=c++11 -I... -L... -lboost_system [fname.cpp] -o [fname]

Comment: Not sure if it applies here but if you're using a stopwatch then the method which executes more OPs will have higher variance because there's a higher chance that the OS will context-switch to another thread/process mid-operation. If that's the case then it's not the method that actually varies in time but it's waiting to get the processor back from the OS more often.

Comment: AFAIK, ptime is wall-clock time, in which case a 10% deviation is nothing to write home about.

Comment: Also note that `2^31` does an XOR and produces `29`, not an exponentation

Comment: With only 1000 iterations, the result are probably affected a lt by the resolution of the timer...

Comment: Timer resolution, context switches, startup time for the process.  What you need is an OS-specific way to track actual CPU time that was given to the process after it is running.

Comment: @rlee827 as noted, I actually did not use 2^31, rather I typed out the full integer value...